# Visual Studio 2019 doesn't display the complete list of class methods

Tags: c++

After update to Visual Studio 2019 I had seen the problem.
In context menu(when I write . or -> after class object) with list of class methods I don't see all methods. But I can manually write name of method and it's ok.
For example, std::shared_ptr hasn't method get() in context menu, but I can write of the method manually.
Why Visual Studio doesn't display all methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First ensure that your code do compile. If you have **errors before** in your file *(or included headers)* like an extra }, IntelliSense might not works.
- If you open large solution or do a lot of change, it can take **some time** before the IntelliSense database get up-to-date.
- If you always have the same problem, then make a project that reproduce the problem and report it to Microsoft using **Report problem** tool. Complaining here won't help improve Visual Studio.
- Also ensure that you explicitly include appropriate headers and see if it fix the problem.

While I don't use `sdt::shared_ptr` often, I have no problem seeing the `get()` method for `std::unique_ptr`.

Obviously, if you use `->` operator, the target class should not be an imcomplete type for IntelliSense to works.

Presently, IntelliSense is limited with function like `std::make_unique` as it seems to only look top level declaration and as such is not able to figure out available constructors.